# DB2 Unable to select distinct column values from inner query

Tags: sql, db2, db2-zos

I have a simple DB2 SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM (SELECT a, b FROM schema.table WHERE APPR_STATUS = 'Approved');
```

When I try sample queries like this over any table on a DB2 DB inside DBeaver, I get the following error:

`SQL Error [56038]: ATTEMPT TO USE A FUNCTION WHEN THE APPLICATION COMPATIBILITY SETTING IS SET FOR A PREVIOUS LEVEL. SQLCODE=-4743, SQLSTATE=56038, DRIVER=4.13.127`

When I looked up for that particular SQLCODE in DB2 support sites, it mentioned this happens because the query won't run, though they don't specify why it won't. Can someone help me figure out why this query won't run?

Comment: Check if this APAR applies at your site :  https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PI84560 , and if not, check if setting the APPCOMPAT special register helps as explained here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.dbconn.doc/doc/c0061167.html

Comment: The second one fixed it for me. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the table expression **alias** as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM (
  SELECT a, b FROM schema.table WHERE APPR_STATUS = 'Approved'
) x
```

See that `x` I added at the end?

Comment: That fixed the query for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mao with his comment above, I executed the following command in DBeaver:

`SET CURRENT APPLICATION COMPATIBILITY = 'V11R1';` and the query got fixed.